# IIS7.5 + Wordpress + Restrict Access to wp-login.php by client IP address

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, security, iis7

I am moving from an Apache host to IIS. One of my sites in Wordpress (running Multi-site) which give me multiple blogs. I have moved all my rules from my .htaccess to the Microsoft URL ReWrite module. I have one section left that will not import.

I want to restrict access to all instances of the file wp-login.php by Client IP address.

In my .htaccess file I did the following:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168
</Files>
```

Any smart ideas on how to accompish this in IIS7.5?

Answer (score 4):

I found this can be done with URL ReWrite

Credit to: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ut0pD2l4z5c#!

from web.config

Be sure to add the ServerVariable you choose (HTTP_X_AdminIPAllowed in my example) to allowed server variables from the URL ReWrite module in the IIS Console.

This example allows access to 192.168.1.* clients to all copies of wp-login.php

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="FlagAdminIPs" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^192\.168\.1\.(1(2[8-9]|[3-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))$" />
            </conditions>
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="HTTP_X_AdminIPAllowed" value="yes" />
            </serverVariables>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Restrict wp-login.php access" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="wp-login.php" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_AdminIPAllowed}" pattern="yes" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```